# Adding an Excel Textbox with win32com

Tags: python, excel, com, win32com

I am trying to add an Excel Textbox to a worksheet... the typical shortcut I use in the Excel GUI is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> and then click where I want the Textbox; however, I don't have access to the COM browser, which leaves me guessing where Microsoft hid the Textbox API under Python's `win32com`...

```
from win32com import client

excel=client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible=True
book=excel.Workbooks.Open("c:/Users/dpennington/Desktop/Blank.xls", False, 
    True)
sheet=book.Worksheets(2)
```

How would I add a textbox (i.e. in the Excel GUI: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>), using Python's `win32com` api? (Specific positioning in the worksheet is up to you...)

Comment: Try openpyxl instead: http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/ if possible? or any of the following for xls files: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @Torxed, if you post an answer that works using openpyxl, I will accept that... `win32com` is not required, but I could not find the right API with openpyxl

Comment: @Mike_pennington Wasn't sure my answer really answered your question completely since i'm afraid i wasn't really sure what you mean by "Textbox"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AddTextbox method of the Shapes object:

```
import win32com.client as client

xl = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("c:/1temp/badacres.xls")
ws = wb.Sheets(1)

tb = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 570, 45, 171, 80)
tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = 'This is a great big test.'
```

You can find more on the AddTextbox method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb209628%28v=office.12%29.aspx).